# InitializeComponent() Error because of 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection'

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

The result in my API look like this :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Yolanda",
        "last_name": "Powlowski",
        "email": "seven01@seven.fr",
        "email_verified_at": "2023-11-28T14:30:16.000000Z",
        "phone_number": "+17152003382",
        "address": "84701 Vicenta Isle Suite 884\nMorarside, OR 63677-5156",
        "created_at": "2023-11-28T14:30:16.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-11-28T14:30:16.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Nat",
        "last_name": "Wolff",
        "email": "seven02@seven.fr",
        "email_verified_at": "2023-11-28T14:30:16.000000Z",
        "phone_number": "+12078430101",
        "address": "5658 Aletha Burg\nPhilipshire, SD 63651-5873",
        "created_at": "2023-11-28T14:30:16.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-11-28T14:30:16.000000Z"
    },
```

[image: Issue]

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Margin="10,10,8,355" Grid.Column="1">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}">
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" ><Run Text="Nom :"/></TextBlock>
            <TextBox FontSize="20" 
                     Height="35" 
                     IsReadOnly="True"
                 
            />
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
```

The ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}" is the cause of my app crashing any tips?

I want to have the content of the result from my api (FirstName, LastName ....) into a TextBox.